# What are all the open standards related to Rule Engine?

Tags: rule-engine

If we need to use plugaable rule engine, what are all the open standards related to it.

How to migrate rule engine "without rewriting rules" for every platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSR-94 is the only standard in wide use but, sadly, won't help you with rewriting rules as it is only a standard for calling the engine. If you want to avoid re-writing rules while either supporting multiple rule engines or moving from one to another then you need to look into a couple of other standards:
[Production Rule Representation](http://www.omg.org/spec/PRR/) (PRR) is a standard under development at OMG. This defines the basic structure of rules and rulesets in rule engines so that an XML structure can be passed around containing rules. This is in beta and is being supported by most of the major rule vendors (though I don't think any have released support yet).
[Rule Interchange Format](http://www.w3.org/2005/rules/wiki/RIF_Working_Group) (RIF) is a standard under development at W3C. This is being kept synchronized with PRR and is focused on the syntax of the rules - how to specify conditions etc. This is also widely supported but similarly support is not yet released.
The idea, and the reason the two teams work together, is to allow rules to be structured according to PRR (allowing them to be shared between modeling tools and rule engines) while exporting the rule engine-specific syntax to RIF so that specific rules can be moved from syntax to syntax.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) says

> Most Java-based rules engines provide
>   a technical call-level interface,
>   based on the [JSR-94](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=94) application
>   programming interface (API) standard,
>   in order to allow for integration with
>   different applications, and many rule
>   engines allow for service-oriented
>   integrations through Web-based
>   standards such as WSDL and SOAP.

In general, it's still an early stage and I don't think there's still a dominating standard on the field. Also see [The Rule Markup Initiative (RuleML)](http://ruleml.org/). Besides JSR-94 and RuleML, [Business Rule Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Rule_Management_System) mentions OMG Business Motivation Model (BMM), OMG SBVR, OMG Production Rule Representation (PRR), W3C RIF, and PMML.

You may also be interested in topics like [BPEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language), [workflow engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine), [workflow application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_application), and [business process management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPMS).

Comment: As the other answer points out, JSR-94 is not very useful in its current form. It just does not specify enough actual details to be of use for most aspects, and specifically nothing regarding how rules are defined/described. :-/